# how to make this axios delete request work?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm creating a bank app with react, node js and MongoDB.
The data is posted through 3 different inputs done by the user, but I'm having problems with the delete request. It is in 3 different classes (props passed accordingly). The error I'm getting says that it cannot read the property _id of undefined. The id is received from the DB. How can I make it work? Thanks in advance!

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      transactions: []
    }
  }

  deleteTransaction = async (transaction) => {
    await axios.delete('http://localhost:8080/transaction', {data: {id: transaction._id }})
    let response = await this.getTransactions()
    this.setState({ transactions: response.data })
  }
```

```
class Transactions extends Component {
    deleteTransaction = () => { this.props.deleteTransaction() }
```

```
class Transaction extends Component {
   <button onClick={this.props.deleteTransaction.bind(this)}><DeleteIcon /></button>
```

Comment: can i see your transaction array data structure? please console.log(transaction) and see the data structure. and also check is transaction an array or object?? the issue is  there have no _id property at transaction object

Comment: @jualahmed It's an object, the id gets created automatically by the DB like this:
`{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5e18fccefbfecb25481c33d4"
  },
  "amount": 21,
  "vendor": "as",
  "category": "ds",
  "__v": 0
}`

Comment: use this.transactions._id.$oid to get this id

Comment: @devPom I have posted an answer for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the bind when it is passed as a prop.

First, you have to remove the **deleteTransaction** function which is declared inside the **Transactions** component

Second, You have to pass the value the transaction argument in **deleteTransaction** function which is declared in App component

```
<button onClick={(event) => this.props.deleteTransaction(transaction)}><DeleteIcon/></button>
```

You haven't passed the value to the callback function which is why you are getting the `cannot read the property _id of undefined`. By default transaction argument value in **deleteTransaction**(App) is undefined. Since you haven't passed any value to the transaction argument, it works as expected.

**Note**:
Try to use React Context API whenever is possible which will avoid the prop drilling.